# Why/when would you use field() for a non-callable default?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-dataclasses

I'm trying to understand when it is correct to use field(default=x).

I understand in a case where the default is callable, it is wrong not to. For instance:

```
@dataclass
class SomeClass:
   obj_content: list = field(default=[])
```

instead of

```
@dataclass
class SomeClass:
   obj_content: list = []
```

But when the default is not, what is the difference?

```
@dataclass
class SomeClass:
   obj_id: int = field(default=0)
```

versus

```
@dataclass
class SomeClass:
   obj_content: int=0
```

Comment: Did you read https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html#dataclasses.field already? What was left unclear?

Comment: BTW in case of an empty list as default you should probably use `default_factory=list`, not `default=[]`.